# Support for Dell XPS 15 Touch Screen

Tags: drivers, kernel, dell, touchscreen

I Will get an XPS 15 via my company soon which will come with Windows preinstalled. This is the basic hardware configuration.

Dell W5170151301SGW10PRO - XPS 15

11th Generation Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-11900H (24MB Cache, up to 4.9 GHz, 8 cores)

15.6" UHD+ (3840 x 2400) InfinityEdge Touch Anti-Reflecitve 500-Nit Display

I intend to do a clean wipe out to set up my Linux desktop, but anyone has experience running linux on this or similar models? I hope it works well? Asking this particularly because this model does not seem to be ubuntu certified in canonical website.

Also, will the latest versions of Ubuntu support this touch screen? I know it has to do with using 5.10+ kernel version, but is there any other driver required? Or is 5.10+ kernel a necessary and sufficient condition for touch screen compatibility of any version?

Comment: You may wish to talk to the company's IT Department FIRST... as they may not ALLOW you to wipe Windows and install Linux. The company may have Windows apps that they need/wish you to run to do your business. They probably won't support it either way.

Comment: Check the Dell web site they say what models are certified for Linux.

Comment: I already got IT's clearance on this. But does Dell have any list of Linux certified equipments? Where to see it?

Comment: Boot the new machine on a Live USB (install media) and choose "try without installing" and check if touchscreen is working- I have a Fujitsu laptop and the touchscreen worked out of the box.